# Typescript return type of intersected functions is mismatched with the inferred type

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, return-type, type-mismatch

As I was trying to extract the return type of a request that is intersected, I came across the this mismatch of the return type and the inferred type. Here is the shortened url https://tsplay.dev/mAxZZN

```js
export {}
type Foo =  (() => Promise<string>) & (() => Promise<any>) ;


type FooResult = Foo extends () => Promise<infer T> ? T : null
//   ^?

const a:Foo = async () => {
        return "";
    }

const b = await a();
//    ^?


type Foo2 =  (() => Promise<any>) & (() => Promise<string>);

type FooResult2 = Foo2 extends () => Promise<infer T> ? T : null
//   ^?

const c:Foo2 = async () => {
    return "";
}

const d = await c();
//    ^?
```

In these 2 above examples the results are mismatched to `FooResult:any b:string` and `FooResult2:string d:any`

To make my example more clear instead of having a `Foo` type I just have a intersected type like `HTTPRequest & {json: () => Promise<Type>}` to have a correct return type of the request json object.

Is there anyway I can make these 2 be matched correctly to same type? If so how? Thanks for the help in advance! <3

Comment: ② What you want is either impossible or not worth the effort; it is a known limitation that using [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to infer from multiple call signatures only consults the last signature, but when calling an overloaded function you get the first one that matches.  You should consider refactoring to avoid intersections of functions if you need to manipulate their types.  Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Oh, I wasn't really sure what was happening while doing `json:func & json:func`. I thought that it somehow overwrote the previous one. Alright then I just `Omit<HTTPRequest, "json"> & {json: Promise<Type>}` and fixed it. Thanks @jcalz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of function types is equivalent to an [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) function type with multiple call signatures.  And there are known limitations when dealing with such types at the type level. Unless you're trying to use overloads and have a strong need for them, you should consider refactoring to use a single call signature instead.

---

When you *call* an overloaded function, the call is resolved with "the most appropriate" call signature; often the *first* one in the ordered list that applies:

```
// call signatures
function foo(x: string): number;
function foo(x: number): string;

// implementation
function foo(x: string | number) {
    return typeof x === "string" ? x.length : x.toFixed(1)
}

const n = foo("abc"); // resolves to first call signature
// const n: number

const s = foo(123); // resolves to second call signature
// const s: string
```

So the return type will depend on the input type.

---

On the other hand, when you try to [*infer*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) from an overloaded function type, the compiler pretty much only infers from the *last* call signature:

```
type FooRet = ReturnType<typeof foo>
// type FooRet = string
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not (string & number) or [string, number]
```

This is mentioned [in the Handbook documentation for using `infer` in conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) and is considered a design limitation of TypeScript, as mentioned in [microsoft/TypeScript#43301](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43301).

There are some possible workarounds to try to tease apart multiple call signature information using conditional types, but they are fragile, and before you even think of using them, you should re-examine your use case.

---

If you've got two call signatures with the same parameter types, then they really will not behave well at all:

```
function bar(): { a: string };
function bar(): { b: number }; // why?
function bar() {
    return { a: "", b: 1 }
}
```

When you call the function you'll get the first return type:

```
const a = bar();
// const a: { a: string; }
```

But when you infer you'll get the last return type:

```
type BarRet = ReturnType<typeof bar>;
// type BarRet = { b: number; }
```

And there doesn't seem to be a reason to have multiple call signatures in such cases.  If you want to get an intersection of return types, you should just have one call signature that does that:

```
function baz(): { a: string } & { b: number } {
    return { a: "", b: 1 }
}
const ab = baz();
// const ab: { a: string; } & { b: number; }
type BazRet = ReturnType<typeof baz>;
// type BazRet: { a: string; } & { b: number; }
```

---

So in your case, `(() => Promise<string>) & (() => Promise<any>)` is equivalent to an overloaded function whose first no-arg call signature returns `Promise<string>` and whose second no-arg call signature returns `Promise<any>`.  So you'll get the first when you call and the last when you infer.  Instead you should just have a single call signature like `() => Promise<string>` or `() => Promise<any>` or whatever your desired type is ([the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) is problematic itself, but I won't digress further here to talk about it).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUAPAXIgzlAJxjAHMBKHMEAWwCMBTAgbgChRJYFlVNKaGCFPIWIlW7aPCQp02YUVKIAPoip1GZRAG8WiPYgL0oIAkigBPAA704wRBkQBeZ4gBE+BSVeIA-PYB0ADb0pFAAFog4GP5QcABiMBj0ACZoAIxkLAC+LCwQCPiqTtzorgCGtBCuZKwA9LWI+WCFYHzqBLlNhbjFMukATADMNSz1jQVQeDgeorksFtaIcagASkbFa8amACpW9AA8CzZ2MgB8ow1HS6vrjvKzuRKcSLRlBGhCWohl0yKKWeJwJIuK93p9ELQ2gJEADEGMAO5hcw+NhA54Qt4fbS6fSGLZIL4-NyuAA0EJwaRh2U6E2+xVBHzqDS6kyJhN+niYVKuACE3psNkYTGBdtZDntbBiCKcmYhefzbtpyap+IwuTlURwpBiAF4fHDs+7-RAAMiVkJV7Rh2P0BiFpiVRNcpOVlJyORZ31o9LKepGY09FQN3w5onVpvNULV3L2iD5OoFd02wtFByOkteOplFzlsfjm2DRJmpHDZq+FrUAnVLCAA)